# Is there any method to fill the combobox in winforms with all country names and flags

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, flags, country

I'm in `C# winforms` and i want to fill combobox with country name and flags in winform (**flag - country name**) but don't have flags and name for all country however i know we can get all country name from `RegionInfo` something like this :

```
List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);

foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);
    if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
        cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);
}
```

But i don't know how can i get all flags, i try to find solution's or components for this work but i don't find any for `winforms` !

Have any method, components or etc for this work ?

Comment: You'll have to get that from some external source or compile your own collection to use.  Here's a [link](http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-illustration-all-country-flags-complete-set-d-isolated-square-icons-image47192988) to a site that has 3D icons.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for link.... i will do...

Comment: You can use that list of cultures to get the ISO 3166 country codes, then load the image from this pack of flag icons http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/